# Linux screen annotations

Tags: linux, drawing, annotation

I'm looking for a Linux (Ubuntu) tool that serves the same purpose as something like Epic Pen on Windows (http://epic-pen.com/). Basically, something that allows me to use a stylus to draw on top of my current screen regardless of whats in the background (powerpoint, video)

Feature wise, I'd like to be able to save an image of current annotations, and quickly display/hide annotations. An additional plus would be the ability to activate the tool with a hotkey

Answer (score 6):

gromit-mpx worked flawlessly on a MINT 20 installation.  I have been having problems with screen annotation software and this is the best one I have used.

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend flameshot: https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot
 
 
 
However, in case that doesn't work for you, there's a few alternatives:

https://github.com/hzbd/kazam

https://github.com/linuxdeepin-packages/deepin-scrot

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/hotshots

From what I could tell, all of them can screenshot and annotate right after, but feel free to correct me if any of them doesn't and I'll fix it here.

Comment: Welcome Archezule!  Please update your answer to include why you highly recommend flameshot.  Thanks!

Comment: Same question here, but the one thing I'm after is that it does *not* work on a screenshot (paint can do that) but on the actual, real live screen. In particular, the screen/annotations background gets refreshed as things happen, and the annotations stay in place. Can these do that ? Epic Pen works like that, so I think this is also what OP is after

Answer (score 2):

Try gromit-mpx
https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx
It works fine on my Debian. I could not to make works it on my Mageia.